# Updating html view when internal variable changes- how?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So, I have navbar which is constant throughout my SPA application.
I have several links inside it (products, register etc.) for navigation purposes.

When I log in, I want, for example, the Register link to disappear. I've read numerous topics here, none of them helped. Can anyone provide me with good explanation.
Here a short version of my approach:

I have login session service which holds data whether some logged in:

```
Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LoginSessionService {
  private isLoggedIn: boolean = false;

  public GetIsLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.isLoggedIn;
  }

  public SetIsLoggedIn(value: boolean): void {
    this.isLoggedIn = value;
    this.loggedIn.next(this.isLoggedIn);
  }

  public loggedIn: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
}
```

Then I have the navbar component class which subscribes to this BehaviorSubject, with constructor injection, as usual:

```
export class WelcomeScreenComponent implements OnInit{

 public isLoggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(private loginSessionService: LoginSessionService) {
   
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.loginSessionService.loggedIn.subscribe(response => this.isLoggedIn = response);
  }

  getLoggedInfo(): boolean {
    return this.isLoggedIn;
  }
}
```

And here is a snippet my html template:

```
    <a *ngIf="getLoggedInfo()" href="link">Shopping Cart</a>
```

I did this implementation according to the exact same problem in another topic, but for me it still does not work.
Also, I have a separate component, in which, when successful login is done, it triggers the whole process with:

```
 private saveLoginSucessInformation() {
    this.loginSessionService.SetIsLoggedIn(true);
    this.isLoggedIn = this.loginSessionService.GetIsLoggedIn();
  }
```

So, basically I am using the LogionSessionService isLoggedIn as global variable, for which I need to detect the changes and change the html accordingly.
I have a feeling that my Lifecycle Hook is not the correct one, because OnInit triggers when starting/ refreshing the App (page).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the method into a getter.

change this:

```
  public GetIsLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.isLoggedIn;
  }
```

to this:

```
 public get isLoggedIncheck(): boolean {
    return this.isLoggedIn;
  }
```

and use in html like:

```
<a *ngIf="isLoggedIncheck" href="link">Shopping Cart</a>
```

or you can directly use `isLoggedIn` in the html :

```
<a *ngIf="isLoggedIn" href="link">Shopping Cart</a>
```

Comment: Okay, I will experiment. Just to say - I am new to Angular.
Maybe, I will have to refresh the page to get my result, or not?

Comment: no, Angular has  two way data binding. which means you don't have to refresh the page to see changes in your variables

Answer (score 1):

In the `WelcomeScreenComponent` there's no need for the `getLoggedInfo()` method. The subscription in the `ngOnInit()` is enough. Simply put the `isLoggedIn` variable of `WelcomeScreenComponent` in the `*ngIf` in the html,

`<a *ngIf="getLoggedInfo()" href="link">Shopping Cart</a>`

and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, but still not working. I updated my code, set the *ngIf="isLoggedIn" but while debugging, the OnInit method is only hit when I refresh the page. When I perform the Login not the whole page is refreshed. The navbar is constant throughout the app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Okay so, I managed to fix things.

1. My Subject wasn't emitting in proper way. I needed to convert it to Observable, then wrap it inside a getter and pass it to my component, like this:
   LoginSessionService:

```
 public getObservable() : Observable<boolean>{
    return this.loggedInSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

Then in my components use this very observable to subscribe and get the emitted values.

Now, there was a 2nd bigger problem:
In both my components I used  providers: [LoginSessionService]
inside

```
@Component ({
providers: [LoginSessionService]
})
```

And also this service was registered in the providers of AppModule.
Since I am new to Angular, I did not realize earlier that I am using 2 new instances of this service inside each component, where providers: [LoginSessionService] was placed as a code. This was my bigger problem. But I fixed it.

Topic is answered.